# Optaplanner: cartesianProductMoveSelector with changeMoveSelector and customMoveFactory fails consistency on Undo

Tags: optaplanner

We have a CustomMove, which works well on its own. Then, if we combine it with changeMoveSelector on another variable using cartesianProductMoveSelector, it fails when using FULL_ASSERT.

Are there any assumptions about using cartesianProductMoveSelector, which we need to cover in our CustomMove?

What we noticed so far:

- CustomMove works on its own
- Fails in combination with changeMove
- Exception presents as UndoMove fail, but the actual CustomMove inside the cartesian product is not generated by Undo (we mark these with a special flag).